# RX Java- Zip n number of Observables using java var args

Tags: java, rx-java

I have below observables

```
Observable<TestEntity1> entity1Observable = getTestEntity1Observable();
Observable<TestEntity2> entity2Observable = getTestEntity2Observable();
....
....
...
...
Observable<TestEntity5> entity5Observable = getTestEntity5Observable();
```

And I wanted to zip these Obsevables using java var args, instead of increasing the number of arguments in Observable.zip which is exactly as below

```
Observable<AggregateEntity>  aggregate = Observable.zip(entity1Observable, 
               entity2Observable, entity3Observable, entity4Observable, 
               entity5Observable, aggregateEntity::setData);

public AggregateEntity setData(TestEntity1 entity1Observable, TestEntity2 entity2Observable, TestEntity3 entity3Observable, TestEntity4 entity4Observable, TestEntity5 entity5Observable) {
        this.entity1Observable = entity1Observable;
        this.entity2Observable = entity2Observable;
        this.entity3Observable = entity3Observable;
        this.entity4Observable = entity4Observable;
        this.entity5Observable = entity5Observable;
        return this;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify your question please, what is your problem ?

Comment: I want to make my setData method to be generic by using varargs to support multiple observables.

Answer (score 0):

zip has [an overloads that receives an Iterable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-). This should be enough to pass any number of items.